# Run a Access SavedExport from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying (and failing) to write a macro in Excel that would:
1. Open a Database that has a password
2. Run a savedexport

So far I have the following, but it still prompts for the password, and gives an error:

```
>"Run-time error '31599':

>The specified name " cannot be set due to one of the following reasons:

>* The specified name is not unique.
>* The specified name is blank.
>* The specified name does not follow [Name of My Database] object-naming rules.
```

MACRO

```
Sub RunSavedExport()

'Open DB and run procedure
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
If Not objAccess Is Nothing Then

    With objAccess
        .OpenCurrentDatabase "O:\2016\DatabaseName.accdb", False, "MS Access;PWD=XXXX"
    .DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    .DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "SavedExportName"
    .DoCmd.SetWarnings True


    End With
End If


'Close Access
If Not objAccess Is Nothing Then
    With objAccess
        .CloseCurrentDatabase
        .Quit
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you use just the password as the third argument, like this? `.OpenCurrentDatabase("O:\2016\DatabaseName.accdb", False, "XXXX")`

Comment: HansUp - using your suggestion avoided the password prompt, but still gave me the error "run-time error...." shown above

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinct possibility that the error is based on remnants of the old 8-character name system, if you possibly at some time have renamed/altered your saved export.

Try renaming your saved export now to a name that begins with a different combination of initial characters than what you've used before. (i.e. not from `SavedExportName` to `SavedExportNameNEW`, but from `SavedExportName` to for instance `NewSavedExportName`).

That did the trick for me!

In fact, using MS VBA 7.1 in MS Access 2007-2013, I have, with success, completely omitted most of the code that you're using, and this simple line does it all:

```
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ("NameOfSavedExport")
```

(Not sure if the parenthesis are needed, but it Works!)
(That being said - I'm running it from within the DB, so you might need most of Your original code after all...)

Hope this helps!